# How to "boolean" shape from point clouds with math nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a grid of point clouds and I need to remove certain sections from them. I created a triangular shape using math nodes, and now I need to figure out how to multiply them so I can then use the result in an instance on points node.

I can't use Selection input because it's needed for another operation
[image]

Comment: I didn't understand your Q ... but I can be only one :)

Comment: I need to cut some point clouds so they dont represent a rectangle shape. I just dont know how to cut these in between Mesh to points and Instance on points nodes. I have a BnW generated texture where I only want points on white spots. @vklidu

Comment: @Sforz Sounds like you're simply looking for the `Delete Geometry` (or `Separate Geometry`) node?

Comment: Like this https://imgur.com/nib5TTT ?

Comment: Ha, looks like yes!) Thannk you! @Kuboå Feeling stupid rn

Comment: Yup, youre right! Thanks too! @vklidu

Answer (score 1):

Its delete geometry node. Thanks to @Kuboå and @vklidu
[image]